# What would cause a JS carousel to not work on iOS & Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have a carousel that I built for a page based on [this guide](https://www.exeideas.com/2022/09/pure-js-infinite-auto-play-slider.html) & it works fine on <s>desktop</s> non-iOS browsers, so not at all on Apple mobile devices (iPhone & iPad). I can't share the URL because of work stuff but the code is essentially the same. This is the first carousel/slideshow like this that I've built from scratch, soo if I'm missing something really obvious, I'm cool with that being pointed out.

I've pasted in a sanitized version of it here, I appreciate any insight in this, I'm just a bit spent at the moment between family holiday drama & working all the time, so a little community assist would do wonders for me atm.

**Edit:** I thought at first that this was only on mobile devices but I've fired up an old Android phone I had to check it out & it worked fine on it, so when I checked in console on Safari, I saw the following error:

*TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'slider.lastElementChild')*

```js
// Carousel
function slider() {
  let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
    slider = document.querySelector(".slider"),
    last = slider.lastElementChild,
    first = slider.firstElementChild,
    btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

  slider.insertBefore(last, first);

  btn.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", movement);
  });
  setInterval(function()
  {
      movement({target:{id:"next"}});
  }, 3000);
  function movement(e) {
    slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
    last = slider.lastElementChild;
    first = slider.firstElementChild;

    const activeSlide = document.querySelector(".active");

    if (e.target.id === "next") {
      slider.insertBefore(first, last.nextSibling);

      activeSlide.classList.remove("active");
      activeSlide.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      slider.insertBefore(last, first);
      activeSlide.classList.remove("active");
      activeSlide.previousElementSibling.classList.add("active");
    }
  }
}
slider();
```

```css
    /* JS Carousel https://www.exeideas.com/2022/09/pure-js-infinite-auto-play-slider.html */
    .slider {
      position: relative;
      width: 100vw;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 550px;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .slide {
      opacity: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      -webkit-transition: 2s all;
      transition: 2s all;
    }

    .slide.active {
      opacity:1;
    }

    .slide.active~.slide {
      transiiton: 250ms all;
    }
    .slider__wrapper {
      position: relative;
    }
    .slider_arrow_box{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 4%;
      left: 45%;
      padding: 3px;
    }
    .slider_arrow_wrapper {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 15px;
      background: blue;
      padding: 7px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1.5px;
      opacity: .6;
    }
    .slider_arrow_wrapper:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    [class*="icono-arrow2"] {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-width: 6px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-bottom-color: transparent;
      border-left-color: transparent;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    [class*="icono-arrow2"]:before {
      right: 0;
      top: -3px;
      position: absolute;
      height: 4px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 32px;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      width: 15px;
      transform-origin: right top;
    }
    [class*="icono"] {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      color: #fff;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    [class*="icono"]:before,
    [class*="icono"]:after {
      content: "";
      box-sizing: border-box;

    }
    [class*="icono-arrow2"][class*="-left"] {
      transform: rotate(-135deg);
    }
    [class*="icono-arrow2"][class*="-right"] {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="slider__wrapper">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slide active">
                    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <h1>Slide 4</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider_arrow_box">
              <div class="slider_arrow_wrapper">
                <i id="prev" class="btn icono-arrow2-left"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="slider_arrow_wrapper">
                <i id="next" class="btn icono-arrow2-right"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding 'touchstart' as an event to monitor, in addition to 'click'?

Comment: That's actually how I noticed that even the automatic rotation wasn't working on mobile. I saw that the click event wasn't working on mobile, which naturally highlighted the fact that, well, crap, it's just not working at all on mobile.

Comment: As it turned out, the script was being called before the HTML was built, which wasn't working. Reordering the page fixed this!

Comment: The buttons need `cursor:pointer` in order to correctly work on mobile ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From what I have experienced lately is that on iOS devices (only noticed on iOS devices) is when I looked at the source code in the web inspector I found `<br>` tags inserted where there shouldn't be, they certainly weren't in the HTML my page was serving.... and these `<br>`s where the direct siblings/children...  who knows why, but to work around don't use `.nextElementSibling`, `.previousElementSibling` or `.children` to get elements, use a class name look up from the context of the parent element. a line or two more code...